# How to change icon image on onErrorType

Tags: jasper-reports

After a lot of searching I have to ask.
Is there a way to change the default icon for missing images in *JasperReports*?
If so anyone have a link for me?

Comment: Are you ready for "*Java* solution"?

Comment: @Alexk Well sure, but I have 30+ reports and growing.  I was looking for a higher level of change.  But I'll take anything.  Java don't scare me ;-)